# ComboBox default item

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I'm writing a simple program in VB with WinForms (well, I guess so, as I have never tried anything like that before). My google-driven development attempt was going pretty well until I tried to make a ComboBox control show one of its items by default.

So there is ComboBox1 with two items ("Item A" and "Item B") added through graphical interface (property *Items* in Properties panel). I go to Form1_Load event description in the code window and add the following line:

```
ComboBox1.SelectedItem = 0
```

That is supposed to make "Item A" the default item preselected when the program starts. But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Use `ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0` instead. Are you aware of something called [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are using 0(an integer) on ComboBox.SelectedItem, but ComboBox.Selected item is not an index to an element, it's an actual object.

This is how you use ComboBox.SelectedItem:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Item A")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Item B")
        ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Item A"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you. Well, I've tried different combinations, and they didn't work. But I've noticed that I'm missing the `Handles MyBase.Load` part, so I added it and now everything works fine.